# Error installing Realm in Terminal through cocoapods

Tags: swift, macos, terminal, realm, cocoapods

I need help trying to fix this error when installing Realm through CocoaPods. Has anyone had this problem? Picture is in the link below. Thanks.

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scnKd.png)

Comment: Next time, it is better to post the output in plain text formatted with ` because in the future, links may break

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your connection is unstable, I would try to change my network to wired and try again

The `git clone`  command failed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an updated cocoapods:

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

Run `pod repo update` to make CocoaPods aware of the latest available Realm versions.

In your Podfile, `add use_frameworks!` and `pod 'RealmSwift'` to your main and test targets.

From the command line, run `pod install`.